# AudioQueue trimming and buffer size

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Even though the application works as expected, I am getting a message in the console that I'd like to understand in more detail.

The setup is as follows. An AVAudioPlayer is created and an .m4a file (03:22 in length and 618 KB in size) is loaded. The file has a bit rate of 23 kbps. I realize that the bit rate is very low, but this is acceptable for the application.

Whenever, I adjust the audio player's currentTime property, I get the following message logged to the console.

> AudioQueue: request to trim 2112 + 0 = 2112 frames from buffer
>   containing 1024 frames

The result of setting the currentTime property is as expected, but I wonder what this message means exactly and what I can do to prevent it from showing up.

Comment: I'm also getting this and would love to know the reason. Did you ever find out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find an answer or even a hint of an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me: Stop player before setting its currentTime property. Then set currentTime, prepareToPlay and play.

```
[avAudioPlayer stop];
[avAudioPlayer setCurrentTime:newCurrentTime];
[avAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avAudioPlayer play];
```

source: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/06/10/iphone-add-an-uislider-for-avaudioplayer/

Comment: [player stop] fixed this error, also if you don´t set a current time afterwards. Thanks a lot!